DateTime object giving me an error when querying an API using JSON
I am using an instance of OpenTripPlanner(route mapping software) and querying its API using JSON.    Below is the code:
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'OTPTimeout': '180000',
}

data2 = '{"query" :"query {trip(from: {coordinates: {latitude:  27.94942 longitude:  -82.47202 }}to:\
      {coordinates: {latitude: 27.99107 longitude: -82.45619 }} dateTime: "2024-11-18T14:00:00.000Z") \
        {tripPatterns {duration distance legs{ distance duration id mode}}}}"}'
           

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/otp/transmodel/v3', headers = headers, data = data2)

json_string = response.text

Error:

Unexpected character ('2' (code 50)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 167]

I have successfully received responses from other queries, but this one, involving a datetime, errors out.  I have tried using escaped strings e.g. "2024-11-18T14:00:00.000Z", and also used formatted strings like %s and then adding the value to the end of the string.  I don't know if a datetime is a special object, or if I should just be giving it to the api as a string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please go over your data2 string.  Please clarify what exactly you wish to pass to the request.post() statement.   data2 doesn't seem like a valid dictionary.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you checked the page at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html A quick web search for "python datetime" gives you the documentation. If you have checked it then it is always worth putting that in your question.

This isn't JSON. The error complains about the string itself, not datetime. You have a single key named "query" that contains "query ...dateTime: "2024-11-18T14: 00: 00.000Z" - a raw double quote inside the value. What were you trying to create? Instead of trying to continue the line use triple quotes so you can just type and indent the string the way you want, including newlines. Even better, construct an object the way you want and serialize it to JSON instead of trying to build the string by hand

data2 is a string. It does not represent valid JSON.

If you want to include quotes inside a string value you need to escape them, eg dateTime: \"2024-11-18T14: 00: 00.000Z\"

What API are you really using? The OpenTripPlanner docs show it's mainly GraphQL, not JSON at all

@PanagiotisKanavos is correct, it is not JSON, it is GraphQL.  I don't know if this is the issue, but is it possible in python to put a string inside a string inside a string?  Because the whole query is the string, the query parameters are inside that string, and the 2024-11-18T14:00:00.000Z is a third string.

I figured it out. Once I figured out it was a GraphQL API, I was able to find code online which slightly changed the requests.post parameters and it worked. You can see below.
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'OTPTimeout': '180000',
}
data2 = 'query {trip(from: {coordinates: {latitude:  27.94942 longitude:  -82.47202 }} ,to: \
      {coordinates: {latitude: 27.99107 longitude: -82.45619 }} dateTime: "2024-11-18T16:00:00" ) \
        {tripPatterns {expectedStartTime expectedEndTime duration distance legs{ distance duration id mode }}}}'\
        
           
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/otp/transmodel/v3', headers = headers, json = {"query": data2})

json_string = response.text


Glad you solved! Consider adding a reference to the online source that helped you. Also briefly commenting what you changed and why it worked could help future readers!
